# How to check if variable is of string type in template class?

Tags: c++, class, templates, initialization, g++

I've written following default constructor for a template class, which signs all values here to 0.
The only idea I have, is to check if `typename T` is of string type and later act with it as with string.

```
vec(const size_t size_ = 0): _size(size_), values(_size? new T[_size]:0){
        for(size_t i = 0; i < _size; i++)
            values[i] = 0;
    }
```

In `main`, I use it this way:

```
vec<int> t1; // default constructor works perfectly
vec<string> s2; // ambiguous overload here (signing string to int)
```

But I get the following error:

> error: ambiguous overload for 'operator=' (operand types are 'std::__cxx11::basic_string' and 'int')

**EDIT:**
The class header looks like that:

```
...
template<typename T>class vec{
    private:
    size_t _size;
    T * values;
    public:
    vec(const size_t size_ = 0): _size(size_), values(_size? new T[_size]:0){
        for(size_t i = 0; i < _size; i++)
            values[i] = 0;
    }

    ...
```

Comment: `std::typeid(T) == std::typeid(std::string)`

Comment: If your goal is to default-construct every element then you don't need the code in the body, just do `values(_size ?  new T[_size]() : 0)`. Adding `()` will default-initialize every element in the array, setting the values to `0` if it's an integer, and an empty string if it's a string.

Comment: @Havenard disagree, if he wanted to check the type in this case he'd use std::is_same and SFINAE, but he doesn't even need to do that.

Comment: @gct I'm just answering the title, I didn't really bother to understand the problem, which is why I didn't post that as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to know the type, you just need to use a better initializer.  Instead of using `0`, use `T{}` or `{}` instead like

```
vec(const size_t size_ = 0): _size(size_), values(_size? new T[_size]:0){
    for(size_t i = 0; i < _size; i++)
        values[i] = T{}; // or values[i] = {};
}
```

and now you get a [value initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) `T` for any type `T`.

You can make the code even shorter and just use

```
vec(const size_t size_ = 0): _size(size_), values(_size? new T[_size]{} : 0) {}
```

and `T[_size]{}` will value initialize the entire array for you.

---

Also, while `0` is an appropriate null pointer value, You should use `nullptr` instead.  This more explcitly conveys that you are requesting a null pointer and it can also save you if for some reason your type becomes no a pointer as it will cause a compiler error.

Comment: Can you explain it please?
So im calling default constructor using T{}?

Comment: @MykhailoBazyshyn Yeah.  `T{}` says create a default `T`.  If `T` is a built in type like `int` then it will get zero initialized.  If it is custom type like a `std::string` then it will create a default constructed string.  The same thing happens with just `{}`.